# lein run/eval unable to resolve symbol

Tags: clojure, namespaces, eval, leiningen

I'm trying to run this code with lein run, but I get this error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: pd in this context

The strange thing is, `lein repl` and calling `(-main)` works just fine, no error.
What am I doing wrong?

```
(ns test.core)

(defn pd [num denom]
  (if (zero? denom)
    0
    (/ num denom)))

(defn -main []
  (println
   ((eval
     (list 'fn
           '[x y]
           '(pd x y)))
    3 4)))
```

Comment: Did you try calling it with a fully qualified namespace `'(test.core/pd x y)`

Comment: To answer the last question "What am I doing wrong?", I'd say resorting to `eval` in a case like this. Just create a macro that expands to the call to `pd`. As for the main question, I'm not sure. If it's eval'd in a namespace that's not `test.core`, `pd` won't be defined.

Comment: Thank you, '(test.core/pd x y) works. But why do I need to do that, I don't have any namespace besides test.core?

Comment: @oopaewem I've never actually used `eval` before, but have you checked the documentation to see what namespaces it evaluates code in? It might default to the user namespace instead of the namespace it was called from.